# How are Environment Variables set in Windows (Not as easy as it sounds)

Tags: windows, environment-variables

***See Update Below***

Let me explain the situation:

In the System Control Panel, I setup `JAVA_HOME` as `C:\Java\JDK1.6`. However, when I went into a terminal window to see what's going on, I got this:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
D:\Program Files\Java\jre6
```

Where in the hell is this getting set, and why isn't it picking up the value I set it in the control panel? Other environment variables I put in are set, but it looks like something is overriding it.

> #### Word of Warning:
>
> Although I'm an Administrator on the system, they've put all sorts of goofy restrictive policies on it. For example, I can't set my Recycle Bin not to warn me when I delete something. The `Property` setting isn't there when you right click on the Recycling Bin. I also can't do `regedit`. To set the environmental properties, I setup a MCC Console, and pull up the System Control Panel thorough there.

---

#### Update

Yes, I know the environment variables don't get reset until I open a new command line prompt. However, this is something I set a couple weeks ago, and the machine had been booted a few times since.

I have it set in the System Variables (the lower box). If I put it in the User Variables (the upper box), it does get set correctly, but my `PATH` is set incorrectly if I put %JAVA_HOME% in the path.

Comment: May be a silly question... Was the terminal window already open before you set the environment variable?  Or was it opened afterward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going back through my questions and tying up all the loose ends...

Turned out that the administrators disabled the ability to set PATH on the system. the admins had a policy that if they didn't understand something, they locked it down. And, since they didn't understand much, they locked everything down.

This was a government office, and the admins locked down anything that didn't involve writing bureaucratic regulations or memos in Microsoft Office that no one bothers to read.

Unfortunately, I was a developer there, so I kept running into these walls. My supervisor quit, and took me to his new site. I'm glad I'm out of there.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the environment variable via the control panel, it only changes the environment in the process that it is running.

When a process starts it will "inherit" the environment of the parent at the time it was launched. Changes afterwards are not propagated to child processes.

You may have to relaunch your terminal, or to be sure, log off then back on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a new command prompt to actually "see" the new variable (or call the `set` command in the cmd window for temporary changes or `setx` for permanent changes).

Environment variables are inherited from the parent process when a process is started. When you change or add a variable in the Control Panel, your shell (i.e. the main explorer.exe process) gets to see the change immediately, but not any other already running process. When you start a new process with explorer.exe as the parent process, e.g. by double-clicking a file or chosing Start+Run, the newly created process will also see the updated environment variable(s).

A nice tool for analyzing such kind of things is [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). It shows you the relationship between parent and child processes and double-clicking a running process shows you a detailed dialog with a tab listing all environment variables of the current process.

Comment: I opened a new command prompt. In fact, the machine had been rebooted several times. I set JAVA_HOME a week or so ago. Today, when I was doing something which needed javac, it failed. I tried executing javac from the command line, and was shocked it wasn't found. I checked JAVA_HOME, and saw it was at the wrong value. I checked the control panel and everything was fine.

Comment: @David W.: Take up this issue with your admins. Only they can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is, all executables are in `bin` folder so you should set `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` inside your `PATH` variable.

You were almost there my friend, it usually happens.
Marce

Comment: I know to use `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in my `PATH`, but the issue went was beyond that. In Windows, sits set up domain policies to override local policies, so no matter what I did locally, `%PATH` could neve be changed. I was not allowed to add anything to `C:\Windows\System32` or any other directory that is in my `PATH`. I wasn't even allowed to turn off those annoying warnings you get when you toss stuff into the Recycle bin. It was a office from hell, and I'm glad I'm out of there.