# How to set JAVA_HOME path in hadoop installation?

Tags: java, path, hadoop

Please can some one how to set JAVA_HOME path in hadoop installation ?? I know that I have to add java path in root/conf/hadoop-env.sh file but I want to know the proper way to set the path in windows 7.

Comment: Duplicate of hundreds of questions? Just search for "set JAVA_HOME Windows"...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229019/windows-java-home-problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438160/java-home-variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492937/windows-ignores-java-home-how-to-set-jdk-as-default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218434/how-are-environment-variables-set-in-windows-not-as-easy-as-it-sounds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551668/how-do-i-set-the-default-java-installation-runtime-windows

Comment: Does this looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7 ?

Answer (score 3):

Adding JAVA_HOME to hadoop-env.sh is sufficient from hadoop perspective.